# looping and copying in bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash

I am a PHP developer. I have lots of files in my `/home/filefolder/` . I am unable to access home directory by my PHP code. So i come to idea of bash scripting. i do not know how to create and execute bash file. I have to copy files from `/home/filefolder1/` to `/home/filefolder2/`.

I have a string of records

```
"0000001.pdf" "0000002.pdf" "0000003.pdf"
```

i want it to loop and copy the files

```
#!/bin/bash

loop{
copy(source path destination path)
}
```

Comment: Why the PHP tag?

Comment: ok i am removing it

Comment: If an answer works for you, please accept it. (Tick the green circle)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This snippet should work:

```
for i in "0000001.pdf" "0000002.pdf" "0000003.pdf"
do
    cp /home/filefolder1/$i /home/filefolder2/
done
```

An alternative would be just to use the following:

```
pushd /home/filefolder1/
cp "0000001.pdf" "0000002.pdf" "0000003.pdf" /home/filefolder2/
popd
```

Comment: is it possible /home/filefolder1/"0000001.pdf" "0000002.pdf" "0000003.pdf" /home/filefolder2/

Comment: No, but you could use `cp /home/filefolder1/{0000001.pdf,0000002.pdf,0000003.pdf} /home/filefolder2/` instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing a one time copy, you don't need to write a script. Assuming you are using bash as your shell, in your terminal execute these commands:

```
$ cd /home/filefolder1
$ cp -p 0000001.pdf 0000002.pdf 0000003.pdf /home/filefolder2
```

The -p switch preserves permissions